# SSIS package deployment from SSDT 2015

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I would like to deploy the project I built with SSDT 2015; after research, I saw some answers but not clear enough. I even reinstall SSDT 2015, still no integration service possible.

- Step 1: creating a **SSISDB** in **Integration Service Catalogs** from SSMS 2016 with right-click. Then I had the error as per picture below.
- Step 2: I went to the location `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\` To look at the file `SSISDBBackup.bak` as per some post, but that file does not exist. I do not have another server where I can copy that file.
- Step 3: I tried to log in using **Integration Services** from SSMS I couldn't log in. I have been searching for this and even going through books, but couldn't find the answer. So to say I am stuck.

Please I need your help to finish the lab, and a thorough step-by-step will be deeply appreciated.

Best Regards

Jean

[image: pic1]

Comment: It sounds like you perhaps installed an express (cut down) version of SQL Server. If you run `SELECT @@VERSION` what does it say (please edit the question with the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the file of SSIDB from the bin folder and if it's not being found there then try searching from the file explorer.
Hope you liked my answer.
Thanks